# Buscando outro atributo com Find

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Se na tabela Cliente possui diversos atributos como: Id, Nome, CPF, Endereço. E o ID é a chave primária, como eu posso buscar através do atributo cpf e retornar um cliente?

Isso tudo obviamente, através da JPA com Hibernate

tentei com esse código

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Cliente c where c.cpf = :cpf"). setParameter("cpf", cpf);
return (Cliente) query.getResultList();
```

mas fica dando esse erro

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class br.com.springboot.model.Cliente (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; br.com.springboot.model.Cliente is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @240e0732)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class br.com.springboot.model.Cliente (java.util.ArrayList is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; br.com.springboot.model.Cliente is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @240e0732)
```

Comment: Parece que ta retornando mais de um resultado, uma lista de Cliente